Zero set of analytic function $f$, $g$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ concides implies that $f$ divides $g$.
If I have two analytic functions $f$ and $g$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\{g=0\}\subset\{f=0\}$, what condition does it need to imply that $\frac{f}{g}$ is analytic? I think here we may need some irreducible condition, but I'm fresh to complex analysis and does not have any clue.
More specifically, if $g$ is an irreducible polynomial, for example $g=z_1^2+\cdots+z_n^2-1$, can we have $\frac{f}{g}$ is analytic?

You certainly need some condition, because $f$ and $f^2$ have the same zero set, but $1/f$ is often not entire.

@SassatelliGiulio Yes. That's why I'm looking for some irreducible condition.

This is a bit of a subtle question, so let me write an answer in parts.

If both $f$ and $g$ are polynomials, and $g$ is irreducible, then Hilbert's Nullstellensatz tells you that
$$f^n = g \cdot h$$
for some polynomial $h$ and some number $n$. If $g$ is irreducible you get that $g$ divides $f$.

For $f,g$ holomorphic, the local question is basically answered by Rückert's Nullstellensatz (which is the analytic version of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz). Consider the two germs $f_x, g_x \in \mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n,x}$. By assumption, the local vanishing locus of $g_x$ is contained in that of $f_x$, and so $g_x$ divides some power of $f_x$, i.e. there is $h_x \in \mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n,x}$ with
$$f_x^n = g_x \cdot h_x.$$
In particular if $g_x$ is irreducible you get $g_x | f_x$. If this holds in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n,x}$, it will also hold in a neighbourhood of $x$.
If you start with an irreducible polynomial $g$, it need not have an irreducible germ $g_x$, but $g_x$ will still be a product of distinct prime elements $g_x = g_1 g_2 \dotsm g_k$, and each of the $g_j$ will divide $f_x$, and so you also get $g_x | f_x$ in that case. So yes if $g$ is an irreducible polynomial and $V(g) \subset V(f)$, then $g$ divides $f$.

Here is an example that Hilbert's Nullstellensatz cannot hold for arbitrary holomorphic functions $\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C$. Basically the problem is that the exponent $n$ from Rückert's Nullstellensatz might depend on the point $x$ you chose. Take for example
$$f(z) = \sin(2\pi z)$$ and let $g = G: \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ be the Barnes $G$-function. This has the funny property, that for each $k \in \mathbb N_0$,
$$G(-k) = 0$$
is a zero of order $k+1$. Then $$\{z : G(z) = 0\} = - \mathbb N_0 \subset \mathbb Z = \{z: f(z) = 0\}.$$
On the other hand, there is no power $f^n$ which is divisible by $G$, because for the order of $G$ at $z = -n$ is $n+1$, whereas $f^n$ only has a zero of order $n$.


